# Using SSL certificate for signing PDF files

Tags: java, itext, keystore, digital-certificate

I have a SSL certificate for my application and I want to use it for digitally signing PDF files using iText. The extension of the certificate is .cer and is provided by a certificate signing authority (CA).

The problem is that I am not able to convert this .cer certificate into java keystore which is required while signing the PDF using itext library. The code that I have is:

This code obviously throws **Invalid keystore format IOException.**

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\abc.cer"), "abcd".toCharArray());
String alias = (String) ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, "abcd".toCharArray());
java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\test.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\signed.pdf");
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
sap.setReason("Test Reason");
sap.setLocation("Test Location");
sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20), 1, null);
stp.close();
```

Please let me know how can i convert a SSL certificate into a java keystore and use it for signing pdf files.

Comment: `abc.cer` is x509 certificate, but you trying to open it as jks keystore.

Comment: @user1516873: I know that, and that is my question, how do i convert it into jks keystore?

Comment: You cannot convert it, you can add x509 certificate to keystore, using `keytool` command (from JRE or JDK) But no much help here, because next line, where you trying to get `PrivateKey` will fail with NPE. x509 certificate doesn't contain and cannot contain private key.

Comment: Ok, By private key, do you mean the .keystore and .csr file which were generated for obtaining this .cer certificate from CA? If yes, i have them as well.

Comment: `.csr` - certificate request. No relation here, forget about it. .keystore - maybe it is what you need. Look into it and check it has private key, using keytool. something like this: `keytool -v -list -keystore path_to_keystore.keystore` You should get something like this: `Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN Your keystore contains 1 entry Alias name: sslcert
Creation date: Mar 22, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry`

Comment: @user1516873: Ok, now I have been able to use that keystore to sign the PDF file. But the problem is that this keystore was created by me (for generating certificate request), hence it is a self signed keystore, which obviously shows signature error on pdf. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Your terminology is very difficult to understand. Your certificate is self-signed? Or what? There is no such thing as `self-signed keystore` Please read first http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X509 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28293/discussion-between-ankit-and-user1516873)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, certificates are not "SSL certificates". They are x.509 certificates, some of which can be used for SSL/TLS authentication. If you have such certificate, you can't use it for other purposes including PDF signing.

Next, .cer file is a public part of the certificate, it doesn't include a private key. You need a certificate *and* a private key to sign anything.

Comment: How do I check the type of certificate that I have. I am using the .cer certificate for apache web server (https website). By private key, do you mean the .keystore and .csr file which were generated for obtaining this .cer certificate from CA?

Comment: @Ankit Check fields KeyUsage and ExtendedKeyUsage in certificate.

Comment: KeyUsage : Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0). There is nothing with ExtendedKeyUsage.

Comment: How do i obtain the certificates for signing and certifying documents? What type of certificates are those?

Comment: @Ankit you need to check Certificate Authority sites for PDF signing certificates, they are called this way.

Comment: See for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437354/itext-what-type-of-certificates-do-people-use-to-automate-pdf-signing-on-linux

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits hi, so do you mean for signing PDF files the website SSLs will not work right (which have subject name like www.abc.com)? so which SSLs should i buy for signing the PDF files?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits also my website ssl showing `Digital signature ,Key encipherment` values, so these are not enough? actually the issue iam getting is the adobe reader showing validity unknown, event the Digicert have in their trusted list